# Xamarin.Forms.WebView Add item to local storage before Visiting URL

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, local-storage

I have created ContenPage with WebView inside xaml (code below). I'am passing webpageURL in constructor. My target is to add item to webview localstorage using javascirpt, before even starting loading passed URL. I tried several methods like

> Browser.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(javascirpt);
>   or 
>    Browser.Evaluate(javascirpt);

before executing in Constructor

> Browser.Source = URL;

or wrapping this methods inside

> Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>{});

but still they didn't work as supposed. Do you know any solutions to my problem ?

```
public partial class WebView : ContentPage
{
public WebView(string URL)
{
    string item = "test";
    string javascirpt = String.Format("localStorage.setItem('ls.item', '{0}')", item);
    Browser.Eval(javascirpt);
    Browser.Source = URL;
}
}
```

Xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="Browser" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
          HeightRequest="1000"
          WidthRequest="1000"
          Navigating="WebOnNavigating"
          Navigated="WebOnEndNavigating" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't recommend that put these code in the constructor .Because the class "WebView" hasn't initialized yet when you call these code.Try to move them to method OnAppearing.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing(); 

   string item = "test";
   string javascirpt = String.Format("localStorage.setItem('ls.item', '{0}')", item);
   Browser.Eval(javascirpt);
   Browser.Source = URL;

}
```

Comment: I even used:
protected async override void OnAppearing() and
response = await Browser.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(javascript);
javascript = "localStorage.getItem('ls.item')";
response = await Browser.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(javascript);

And i always receiving null in response.
Only after locking and unlocking phone on WebView page, I finally receive "test" in response.

Comment: Why not pass test by url in some page and set the variable,